# pivottable.js + nreco + subtotals.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pivottable.js

I've started using pivottable.js (http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/) in a project, but I would like to use some features available in few plugins:

1. subtotals.js (http://nagarajanchinnasamy.com/subtotal) for collapse/expand rows and columns + subtotals
2. nreco extension (https://www.nrecosite.com/pivot_table_aspnet.aspx) for the responsive UI, sorting, bootstrap twitter integration...

Is it possible to use both at the same time?